# issues in clearing notifications in Android

Tags: android, push-notification

I have cleared notification on the clicking on the notification. But when the next notification is pushed the cleared one also get stacked with the newly created. Any solution for this?
The issue is not about clearing notifications, it is about why the already cleared notification appears again.

Comment: i hav used NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
builder.setAutoCancel(true);

Comment: but firstly on the clicke it gets cleared but when the next notification is pushed, the the both are stacked